# How to send time Zone along with Date-Time format?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, momentjs

I am having driverTime = `2018-10-06T14:16:18.120Z`

```
let times = this.state.driverTime;
let utc = moment(times).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
```

when I prints `utc` I am getting `2018-10-06 19:46:18` along with this I need Time zone also like `2018-10-05 04:00:00 IST`.

But I am unable to send time zone along with this format.

I am using moment.js.

Comment: Any one can you please give any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

you can include time zone data from the [moment timezone page](https://momentjs.com/timezone/)

assuming that with "IST" you mean India Standard Time, you can use this

```
let times = this.state.driverTime;
let istTimeDate = moment.tz(driverTime, "Asia/Calcutta").format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss z');
```

with this you get

```
2018-10-06 19:46:18 IST
```

```js
let driverTime = "2018-10-06T14:16:18.120Z"
let istDate = moment.tz(driverTime, "Asia/Calcutta").format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss z');

document.getElementById('istDate').innerText = istDate
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
<div id="istDate"></div>
```

I hope I've helped

Comment: showing error: _moment2.default.tz is not a function

Comment: @user9883888 if you are working with npm you must install the package using `npm install moment-timezone --save`
you must also add `import moment from 'moment-timezone';` instead of `import moment from 'moment';`

Comment: after I installed moment-timezone, json.js data error is coming.

Comment: you can create a snippet of jsfiddle code to replicate the error?